# How do I save my graphics settings in Lost Planet 3?

Tags: lost-planet-3

I can't believe I have to ask this question, but I just finished downloading LP3 and can't seem to save my settings. I've change my Texture Quality and World Detail up to "Very High" but it doesn't save it. My options are Backspace (which resets to default), Enter (which either does nothing or changes the option I have open) or Esc, which asks me if I want to quit without saving. I can't see an option for actually saving my options before I quit.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that small blue line on the side? That's a scroll bar.

[image]

Drag down, click "Apply settings" and you're done. Too many animated and glowing things doesn't make it easy to spot. Derp.

Comment: **ATTN UI design people**: If you do stuff like this _you are a bad person_. Now go and think about what you've done...